# Need to print sorted map value like below format in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-11

I'm sorting the Employee Data by grouping the employee number and employee salary. Excepted output I got, but I need to store this details in a fixedlength file. So I need to print by below format.

```
public class SortData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
                      new Employee("102", "300", "100", "200"),
                      new Employee("101", "200", "80", "120"),
                      new Employee("102", "100", "50", "50"), 
                      new Employee("103", "300", "100", "200"),
                      new Employee("101", "200", "80", "120"),
                      new Employee("101", "100", "50", "50"));

        
        Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> map = employees.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpNo, 
    Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpSal)));
        
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}



class Employee {

    private String empNo;
    private String empSal;
    private String empHra;
    private String empPf;

    // getter
    // setter

  }
```

The above code's output is as below.

```
{101={100=[Employee(empNo=101, empSal=100, empHra=50, empPf=50)], 200=[Employee(empNo=101, 
  empSal=200, empHra=80, empPf=120), Employee(empNo=101, empSal=200, empHra=80, empPf=120)]}, 
  102={100=[Employee(empNo=102, empSal=100, empHra=50, empPf=50)], 300=[Employee(empNo=102, 
  empSal=300, empHra=100, empPf=200)]}, 
  103={300=[Employee(empNo=103, empSal=300, empHra=100, empPf=200)]}}
```

I need to print this out put in a fixedlength file. So I need the output as below.

```
1011005050
10120080120
10120080120
1021005050
102300100200
103300100200
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: How do you want the records to be sorted - as strings or by integers? Should employee id `9` come before `10` or is the other way around?

Comment: Already Excepted output I got. But i'e in key, value.

Comment: You aren't doing any sorted - you are relying on the default ordering of the generated map from the groupingBy.

Comment: Do you have to sort the records *by employee no* and/or sort records *for an employee by salary*?

Comment: For Ex: employee 101 got 100 in 1st month, 200 in 2nd and 3rd month.
It should be 101100
    101200
    101200
Then second employee information.

Here I'm doing 1st employee Num ASC then related salary again in ASC format

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I need to sort the records by employee no and then need to sort records for an employee by salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the maps in current implementation are NOT sorted.

Second, it may be redundant to sort the *maps*.  It appears that in order to print the input data, just the input list needs to be sorted by `empNo` and `empSal`:

```java
Comparator<Employee> sortByNoAndSal = Comparator
        .comparing(Employee::getEmpNo)
        .thenComparing(Employee::getEmpSal);

employees.sort(sortByNoAndSal);
```

Last, to print/output an instance of `Employee` specific method should be implemented (by overriding `Employee::toString`, or creating specific method).  Aside note - required output seems to be missing a delimiter between fields of `Employee`.

```java
// class PrintData
public static void printEmployee(Employee emp) {
    String delimiter = ""; // fix if necessary
    System.out.println(String.join(delimiter, emp.getNo(), emp.getSal(), emp.getHra(), emp.getPf()));
}

// invoke this method
employees.forEach(PrintData::printEmployee);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
List<String> result = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpNo, Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpSal)))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> buildOutput(e).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());



private List<String> buildOutput(Map<String, List<Employee>> entry) {
    return entry.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(this::buildOutputForEmployee))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private String buildOutputForEmployee(Employee em) {
    return String.format("%s%s%s%s", em.getEmpNo(), em.getEmpSal(), em.getEmpHra(), em.getEmpPf());
}
```

to print the result:

```
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

```
1011005050
10120080120
10120080120
1021005050
102300100200
103300100200
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, you would like to sort by *employee number* and then by the *employee salary*.

Currently, you aren't sorting, but relying on the default ordering of the returned map type from the *groupingBy* operation.

**1. Use a TreeMap when grouping**

You can specify the type of the map to be used for *groupingBy* by passing a Supplier argument. Unfortunately, you also have to pass the collector in that case (*toList()*).

```
 Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> map = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpNo,
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::valueOf)),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpSal,
                            () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::valueOf)),
                            Collectors.toList())));
```

I'm using a comparator to sort by the *integer value* of the employee number and salary in the TreeMap<sup>1</sup>.

You can print it as (in your case, you will be writing each record into a file).

```
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream())
        .flatMap(innerEntry -> innerEntry.getValue().stream())
        .forEach(emp -> System.out.println(buildRecord(emp)));
```

where `buildRecord` just concatenates the field of the Employee class.

```
private static String buildRecord(Employee employee) {
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append(employee.getEmpNo())
            .append(employee.getEmpSal())
            .append(employee.getEmpHra())
            .append(employee.getEmpPf())
            .toString();
}
```

**2. Sort the list**

But there is no need to group and operate on a complicated data structure. You can simply sort it using a comparator.

```
employees.sort(Comparator.<Employee>comparingInt(emp -> Integer.parseInt(emp.getEmpNo()))
            .thenComparingInt(emp -> Integer.parseInt(emp.getEmpSal())));
```

This sorts the employees list by employee id/number and then by salary <sup>1</sup>.

Print it as,

```
employees.forEach(employee -> System.out.println(buildRecord(employee)));
```

---

<sup>1 - This assumes the employee number and salary are integers. You can change it as per your need.</sup>